# How to create new column with positive instead negative values

Tags: pandas

Okay, I have a pandas dateframe like shown beneath.

```
Date        Time            Value/MWh
01.08.2009  00:00 - 01:00   0
01.08.2009  01:00 - 02:00   -100
01.08.2009  02:00 - 03:00   80
01.08.2009  03:00 - 04:00   50
```

If there is a value < 0, I wanted to have this value as a positive value in a new column.
If that es the case, in the left columns shoult be a 0.

It have to look like this:

```
Date        Time            Value/MWh
01.08.2009  00:00 - 01:00   0   0
01.08.2009  01:00 - 02:00   0   100
01.08.2009  02:00 - 03:00   80  0
01.08.2009  03:00 - 04:00   50  0
```

How can I get this?

Comment: I have some ideas with loops (e.g. with Numpy), but neither with pandas.

Comment: have a look at [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) this is a trivial thing to do so give it a try and come back when you are stuck

Comment: But I can`t use np.XYZ in connection with Pandas dateframes, right?

Comment: Says who? I can tell you for a fact that pandas is compatible with numpy: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe-interoperability-with-numpy-functions

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
df['new'] = 0
df.new.loc[df['Value/MWh']<0] = df['Value/MWh'].abs()
df['Value/MWh'].loc[df['Value/MWh']<0] = 0
```

You should avoid to use strange column names, they can generate errors.

Comment: Thanks. But I get the following error: TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'

Comment: @EP1986 that means the dtype of your columns are strings and not ints/floats. You need to convert whatever columns are strings to ints `df['Value/MWh'] = df['Value/MWh'].astype(int)`